# Getting Bonus Pay to Calculate

Tags: c++

I've got two ifs, the first if which is the overtime if works, but i cannot get the 2nd if to work, which is the bonus pay if days work is greater than 5.
It's not ready the if code i typed for bonuspay,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    float ftax, stax, SDI, SS, hw, hp, dw(0), pay, netpay, gp, OvertimePay = 0,
            bonusPay(0);
    int daysWorked(0);

    cout << "please enter the hoursWorked: ";
    cin >> hw;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "please enter the hourlyPay: ";
    cin >> hp;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "please enter the daysWorked in the week: ";
    cin >> dw;

    if (hw > 40) {
        OvertimePay = (hw - 40) * hp * .5;
        if (daysWorked > 5) {
            bonusPay = (hw - 40) * hp * .25;

        }
    }

    gp = (hw * hp) + (OvertimePay) + (bonusPay);
    ftax = gp * .10;
    stax = gp * .08;
    SDI = gp * .01;
    SS = gp * .06;
    netpay = gp - (ftax + stax + SDI + SS);

    cout << " grosspay =\t\t\t\t\t" << gp << endl;
    cout << " federal taxes =\t\t\t\t" << ftax << endl;
    cout << " state taxes =\t\t\t\t\t" << stax << endl;
    cout << " SDI =\t\t\t\t\t\t" << SDI << endl;
    cout << " Social Securities =\t\t\t\t" << SS << endl;
    cout << " netpay =\t\t\t\t\t" << netpay << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" << endl;

    cout << " grosspay =                    " << gp << endl;
    cout << " federal taxes =               " << ftax << endl;
    cout << " state taxes =                 " << stax << endl;
    cout << " SDI =                         " << SDI << endl;
    cout << " Social Securities =           " << SS << endl;
    cout << " netpay =                      " << netpay << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" << endl;

    cout << left;
    cout << setw(30) << " grosspay =" << gp << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " federal taxes =" << ftax << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " state taxes =" << stax << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " SDI =" << SDI << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " Social Securities =" << SS << endl;
    cout << setw(30) << " netpay =" << netpay << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: _'It's not ready the if code i typed for bonuspay'_ Elaborate please. Did you already debug step through your code? What are the values when the `if()` statements are executed? And **why are you asking the same question twice**??

Comment: the if statements states if days worked > 5 the bonus pay will calculate with the formula above, but it doesnt so calculate when i debug it, just completely ignores it

Comment: im not asking the same question, it's just the same code with another added if that i cannot get to work

Comment: @user _'the if statements states if days worked > 5'_ Check this out: `int daysWorked(0);` So where after this line of code `daysWorked` (which is used in your `if()` statements) should ever be set to a value greater than `5`?? Can you point me there please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change
 `cin >>dw` to `cin >>daysWorked`

Comment: To avoid this mistake in the future, it's good practice to declare variables as you need as opposed to at the top of the function body.

Comment: @user3330862 You're going to repost this, and accept solutions chunk by chunk, do you?

Comment: i will edit my old question if i have another problem from now on

Answer (score 1):

As from your question:

> but i cannot get the 2nd if to work, which is the bonus pay if days work is greater than 5

Despite it's not completely clear what you're asking, one problem in your code for sure is that you check for the `daysWorked` value

```
if (daysWorked > 5) {
   // ...
```

but you never set it again after initialization

```
 int daysWorked(0);
```

anywhere I could spot in your code sample.

Thus the value of `daysWorked` will always be `0`, and the code in the `if()` clauses is *ignored*.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two mistakes here.
You initialised

```
float dw(0);
```

and

```
int daysWorked(0);
```

There is no reason for you to initialise that way seeing through your code, just leave it at

```
float dw; 

int daysWorked;
```

Another problem I see in your code is, you are storing the value of days worked into dw as such

```
cout << "please enter the daysWorked in the week: ";
cin >> dw;
```

but yet you are checking for daysWorked

```
if (daysWorked > 5)
```

and in between there wasnt any code leading up to transferring the value of dw to daysWorked.

---

My advice is to change both dw and bonusPay from

```
float dw(0); 
float bonusPay(0);
```

to

```
float dw;
float bonusPay;
```

and delete

```
int daysWorked(0);
```

lastly

```
if (hw > 40) {
    OvertimePay = (hw - 40) * hp * .5;
    if (dw > 5) {
        bonusPay = (hw - 40) * hp * .25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show original and difference somehow, editing instructions aren't going to work well ...